# Remove blank values from array using C#

Tags: c#

How can I remove blank values from an array?

For example:

```
string[] test={"1","","2","","3"};
```

in this case, is there any method available to remove blank values from the array using C#?

At the end, I want to get an array in this format:

```
test={"1","2","3"};
```

which means 2 values removed from the array and eventually I get 3.

Comment: How do you get the array content, maybe something could be done their

Answer (score 238, accepted):

If you are using .NET 3.5+ you could use LINQ (Language INtegrated Query).

```
test = test.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Should probably use String.IsNullOrEmpty to be safe, otherwise null values will make it into the new array.

Comment: I had to add x.Trim() to also get rid of values that contained only spaces : test = test.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Trim())).ToArray();

Comment: String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace would also work, then you wouldn't have to trim every value

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but should there not be an extra "x" in there? `test.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty())` not be `test.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))`.

Answer (score 38):

You can use Linq in case you are using .NET 3.5 or later:

```
 test = test.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

If you can't use Linq then you can do it like this:

```
var temp = new List<string>();
foreach (var s in test)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        temp.Add(s);
}
test = temp.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

I write below code to remove the blank value in the array string.

```
string[] test={"1","","2","","3"};
test= test.Except(new List<string> { string.Empty }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use two options, white spaces and empty:

```
test = test.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
test = test.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Good answer this is relevant if for example you're parsing a CSV file (or string) and you end up with fields that are filled with white spaces.

Comment: The IsNullOrWhiteSpace() method actually considers an empty string (with no whitespace) as having whitespace, so using both IsNullOrEmpty() and IsNullOrWhiteSpace() is redundant.

Comment: test = test.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Trim())).ToArray();

do the same trick and doesn't need to call it twice

Answer (score 2):

This might have been old, but you could try

```
string[] test = new[] { "1", "", "2", "", "3" };
test = string.Join(",", test).Split(new string[] { "," }, Stringsplitoptions.Removeemptyentries);
```

Join the array and split again with the empty items removed.