# Find and remove items from array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string array. I need to remove some items from that array. but I don't know the index of the items that need removing.

My array is : string[] arr= {" ","a","b"," ","c"," ","d"," ","e","f"," "," "}.

I need to remove the " " items. ie after removing " " my result should be 
arr={"a","b","c","d","e","f"}

how can I do this?

Comment: What version of .NET? Some LINQ extension methods introduced in .NET 3.5 would be perfect.

Comment: there are a few questions and answers like this already here. check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457453/remove-element-of-a-regular-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove blank values in the array using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814811/remove-blank-values-in-the-array-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
  string[] arr = {" ", "a", "b", " ", "c", " ", "d", " ", "e", "f", " ", " "};
  arr = arr.Where(s => s != " ").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

This will remove all entries that is null, empty, or just whitespaces:

```
arr.Where( s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToArray();
```

If for some reason you only want to remove the entries with just one whitespace like in your example, you can modify it like this:

```
arr.Where( s => s != " ").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using LinQ

```
using System.Linq;


string[] arr= {" ","a","b"," ","c"," ","d"," ","e","f"," "," "}.
arr.Where( x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();
```

or depending on how you are filling the array you can do it before

```
string[] arr = stringToBeSplit.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

then empty entries will not be put into your string array in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can use Except to remove blank value

```
string[] arr={" ","a","b"," ","c"," ","d"," ","e","f"," "," "}.
arr= arr.Except(new List<string> { string.Empty }).ToArray();
```