# Quick Search out of bounds of array and confusing array behaviour

Tags: c#, quicksort, parallel-arrays

I'm having multiple problems with my program (C#.NET) and have no idea what's causing them.

The program is intended to sort a list of names and birthdays (formatted `first name,last name,DD/MM/YYYY`) in ascending and descending order by first name, last name, and birthday. It is also to have other functions which have not yet been implemented.

The first problem is in the `quikSortStr` method. The program crashes in the first `if` block, stating that `j` is out of the bounds of the array. This happens whether or not `mode == "asc"`.

The second, and more confusing problem is that when the values are loaded from a text file, every odd-indexed value of `first` and `last` will be null, while each odd-indexed value of `bDay` will be `1/1/0001`.

I've included the full program below for reference, a quicksort method and the use of parallel arrays are required. My apologies for the lack of comments.

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm completely stumped.

```
namespace Names_Arrays
{
public partial class frmNamArrays : Form
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA");
    string[] first;
    string[] last;
    DateTime[] bDay;
    string order = "asc";
    string format = "d/M/yyyy";

    public frmNamArrays()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void write()
    {
        string[] lines = new string[first.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            lines[i] = first[i] + ',' + last[i] + ',' + bDay[i].ToString(format);

        txtbxNames.Clear();
        txtbxNames.Lines = lines;
    }

    private void load()
    {
        string[] lines = txtbxNames.Lines;

        first = new string[lines.Length];
        last = new string[lines.Length];
        bDay = new DateTime[lines.Length];

        int i = 0;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] data = line.Split(',');

            //There aren't any lines that split to a string[] of length less than three,
            //but for some reason the program kept believing there are.
            //patched that leak.

            if (data.Length == 3)
            {
                first[i] = data[0];
                last[i] = data[1];
                bDay[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(data[2], culture);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    public DateTime[] quikSortTim(DateTime[] primary, string mode, int left, int right)
    {
        if (primary.Length > 1)
        {
            int i = left, j = right;
            DateTime pivot = primary[left + (right - left) / 2];

            while (i <= j)
            {
                if (mode == "asc")
                {
                    while (DateTime.Compare(primary[i], pivot) < 0)
                        i++;
                    while (DateTime.Compare(primary[j], pivot) > 0)
                        j--;
                }
                else
                {
                    while (DateTime.Compare(primary[i], pivot) > 0)
                        i++;
                    while (DateTime.Compare(primary[j], pivot) < 0)
                        j--;
                }
                if (i <= j)
                {
                    DateTime holdoverB = primary[i];
                    primary[i++] = primary[j];
                    primary[j--] = holdoverB;

                    string holdover = last[i - 1];
                    last[i] = last[j + 1];
                    last[j] = holdover;

                    holdover = first[i - 1];
                    first[i] = first[j + 1];
                    first[j] = holdover;

                }
            }
            if (j > left)
                primary = quikSortTim(primary, mode, left, j);
            if (i < right)
                primary = quikSortTim(primary, mode, i, right);
        }
        return primary;
    }

    public string[] quikSortStr(string[] primary, string type, string mode, int left, int right)
    {
        if (primary.Length > 1)
        {
            int i = left, j = right;
            string pivot = primary[left + (right - left) / 2];

            while (i <= j)
            {
                if (mode == "asc")
                {
                    while (String.Compare(primary[i], pivot) < 0)
                        i++;
                    while (String.Compare(primary[j], pivot) > 0)
                        j--;
                }
                else
                {
                    while (String.Compare(primary[i], pivot) > 0)
                        i++;
                    while (String.Compare(primary[j], pivot) < 0)
                        j--;
                }
                if (i <= j)
                {
                    string holdover = primary[i];
                    primary[i] = primary[j];
                    primary[j] = holdover;
                    if (type == "first")
                    {
                        holdover = last[i];
                        last[i] = last[j];
                        last[j] = holdover;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        holdover = first[i];
                        first[i] = first[j];
                        first[j] = holdover;
                    }
                    DateTime holdoverBeta = bDay[i];
                    bDay[i] = bDay[j];
                    bDay[j] = holdoverBeta;
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
            }
            if (j > left)
                primary = quikSortStr(primary, type, mode, left, j);
            if (i < right)
                primary = quikSortStr(primary, type, mode, i, right);
        }
        return primary;
    }

    private void frmNamArrays_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbxNames.Width = this.Width - 40;
        txtbxNames.Height = this.Height - 157;
    }

    private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        load();

        switch (cbobxCategory.Text)
        {
            case ("First Name"):
                first = quikSortStr(first, "first", order, 0, first.Length - 1);
                break;
            case ("Last Name"):
                last = quikSortStr(last, "last", order, 0, last.Length - 1);
                break;
            case ("Birthday"):
                bDay = quikSortTim(bDay, order, 0, bDay.Length - 1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        write();
    }

    private void cbobxOrder_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbobxOrder.Text == "Ascending")
            order = "asc";
        else
            order = "desc";
    }

    private void displayfile(string name)
    {
        StreamReader fileData = new StreamReader(name);

        txtbxNames.Lines = fileData.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');

    }

    private void mnuOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
        open.Title = "Select a text file...";

        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && open.FileName != "")
            displayfile(open.FileName);
    }

    private void mnuExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you considered writing a unit test?  Separate your sorting logic into its own class and then write a test with sample data.  Have you considered using a Person class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to saravanan for pointing out my first mistake. The out of range error was caused by an accidental incrementation of `j` in the wrong direction. The fixed methods are

```
    public DateTime[] quikSortTim(DateTime[] primary, string mode, int left, int right)
    {
        if (primary.Length > 1)
        {
            int i = left, j = right;
            DateTime pivot = primary[left + (right - left) / 2];

            while (i <= j)
            {
                if (mode == "asc")
                {
                    while (DateTime.Compare(primary[i], pivot) < 0)
                        i++;
                    while (DateTime.Compare(primary[j], pivot) > 0)
                        j--;
                }
                else
                {
                    while (DateTime.Compare(primary[i], pivot) > 0)
                        i++;
                    while (DateTime.Compare(primary[j], pivot) < 0)
                        j--;
                }
                if (i <= j)
                {
                    DateTime holdoverB = primary[i];
                    primary[i] = primary[j];
                    primary[j] = holdoverB;

                    string holdover = last[i];
                    last[i] = last[j];
                    last[j] = holdover;

                    holdover = first[i];
                    first[i] = first[j];
                    first[j] = holdover;

                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }
            if (j > left)
                primary = quikSortTim(primary, mode, left, j);
            if (i < right)
                primary = quikSortTim(primary, mode, i, right);
        }
        return primary;
    }

    public string[] quikSortStr(string[] primary, string type, string mode, int left, int right)
    {
        if (primary.Length > 1)
        {
            int i = left, j = right;
            string pivot = primary[left + (right - left) / 2];

            while (i <= j)
            {
                if (mode == "asc")
                {
                    while (String.Compare(primary[i], pivot) < 0)
                        i++;
                    while (String.Compare(primary[j], pivot) > 0)
                        j--;
                }
                else
                {
                    while (String.Compare(primary[i], pivot) > 0)
                        i++;
                    while (String.Compare(primary[j], pivot) < 0)
                        j--;
                }
                if (i <= j)
                {
                    string holdover = primary[i];
                    primary[i] = primary[j];
                    primary[j] = holdover;
                    if (type == "first")
                    {
                        holdover = last[i];
                        last[i] = last[j];
                        last[j] = holdover;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        holdover = first[i];
                        first[i] = first[j];
                        first[j] = holdover;
                    }
                    DateTime holdoverBeta = bDay[i];
                    bDay[i] = bDay[j];
                    bDay[j] = holdoverBeta;
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }
            if (j > left)
                primary = quikSortStr(primary, type, mode, left, j);
            if (i < right)
                primary = quikSortStr(primary, type, mode, i, right);
        }
        return primary;
    }
```

I did not find a solution for the second issue *per se*. I did, however, discover that all of the elements that read `",,1/1/0001"` were added, and did not replace any names. Using this, I added to the array `lines` only the index values that did not contain `"1/1/0001"`. I then used `lines = lines.Where(s => s != null).ToArray();` to shorten `lines` by eliminating all of the now null-type values. The modified function is below.

```
private void write()
    {
        string[] lines = new string[first.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            if (bDay[i].ToString(format) != "1/1/0001")
                lines[i] = first[i] + ',' + last[i] + ',' + bDay[i].ToString(format);

        lines = lines.Where(s => s != null).ToArray();

        txtbxNames.Clear();
        txtbxNames.Lines = lines;
    }
```

Thanks for the help. I found the resource for my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375585/find-and-remove-items-from-array-in-c-sharp).

EDIT: It seems the problem is inherent in `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`. I'm not sure why, but it can be completely avoided by using `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filepath)`. In the original code, I would replace

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(name);
lines = file.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
```

with

```
lines = File.ReadAllLines(name);
```

and add `using System.IO;`.

Comment: For your kind information, by default the Sort API internally uses QuickSort in .Net. Thanks for posting the solution for others to use as a reference.

Comment: It's not so much a solution as a workaround, but thanks. Unfortunately for me, I am also required to write my sorting algorithms from scratch, but I'll keep that in mind for when I don't have these conditions on me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the code as below in the `quikSortStr` method inside the `if (i <= j)` loop

```
    DateTime holdoverBeta = bDay[i];
    bDay[i] = bDay[j];
    bDay[j] = holdoverBeta;
    i++;
    j--;//was: j++;
```

and this will fix the issue.

Comment: I can't believe I did that.