# Remove elements from an array in C#

Tags: c#

I have array something like this

`string[] arr = ['a', '', 'c', 'f', ''];`

I want to remove null elements from the same.

How  can I remove the required elements in C#?

Comment: none of those elements are null, or strings for that matter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814811/remove-blank-values-in-the-array-using-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309072/remove-all-empty-elements-from-string-array

Comment: Can you even have an empty char?

Comment: @RGraham Nope. `char` is a value type, so the closest you could do is the `NUL` character, `\0`. It's great when users post questions about code that won't even compile.

Comment: Check the Array.Clear() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it as

```
arr = arr.Where(x => x != "").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] notNullStrings = arr.Where(it => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(it)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Those are not strings

Comment: @PatrickHofman oopss!

Comment: Regardless, it will remove strings that are null or empty which is what the question asked for, another improvement to your answer should be `.Where(!string.IsNullOrEmpty)` but i'm not at a computer where I can test this

Comment: @Sayse IMO string.IsNullOrEmpty() == false is easier to read than !string.IsNullOrEmpty()

Comment: It is less efficient though as it adds an extra comparison, although this may get handled by the compiler, it may not for some other compilers

Comment: @Sayse Could you provide any proof? I'm interesting to see that. Thanks

Comment: In terms of the compiler proof I don't at the minute but what your instruction is saying is `true == false ? true : false` which is a very apparent extra instruction. It is very probable that the compiler will optimise this to just do what `!true` does but then its something that can easily be written into code