# Removing null elements from an object[,] array c#

Tags: c#, null

How can I remove all `null` elements from an array `object[,]` in C#. I've already seen the similar question in StackOverflow : [Remove blank values in the array using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814811/remove-blank-values-in-the-array-using-c-sharp)

The problem is they are using a method called `Where()` to solve the problem with a simple array type `object[]`, but I'm dealing with an array type `object[,]` and there is unfortunately no method `Where()` implemented for this class. For example :

```
object[,] data = new object[2,2]{{null,null},{1,2}};
```

Then, `data` contains :

```
[0, 0] [object]:null
[0, 1] [object]:null
[1, 0] [object]:1
[1, 1] [object]:2
```

As you can see (in my specific case), if one element is null then all the row of this element is null. I would like to get :

```
[0, 0] [object]:1
[0, 1] [object]:2
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is as follows:

- Count how many rows you would like to remove
- Create an array of the appropriate size
- Copy rows that you would like to keep

Use a helper method to detect rows with a `null`:

```
static bool RowHasNull(object[,] data, int row) {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, data.GetLength(1)).Any(c => data[row,c] == null);
}
```

Now the implementation would look like this:

```
var oldRowCount = data.GetLength(0);
var newRowCount = oldRowCount - Enumerable.Range(0, oldRowCount).Count(r => RowHasNull(data, r));
if (newRowCount == 0) ... // the array is empty, do something about it - e.g. throw an exception
var res = new object[newRowCount, data.GetLength(1)];
int r = 0;
for (var row = 0 ; row != oldRowCount ; row++) {
    if (RowHasNull(data, row)) {
        continue;
    }
    for (int c = 0 ; c != data.GetLength(1) ; c++) {
        res[r,c] = data[row, c];
    }
    r++;
}
return res;
```

Comment: Also if “if one element is null then all the row of this element is null” is true then `RowHasNull` can be `data[row, 0] == null`. (Is that `Enumerable.Range` parenthesis in the right spot?)

Comment: @Ry- Right, the parenthesis was in a wrong spot. You are also right about `data[row,0]` but since adding a little generalization "costs" only one line of code, I figured I might as well do it.

Comment: Awesome !
Thank you very much, this solved my issue !

You should also correct your second line : var newRowCount = oldRowCount - Enumerable.Range(0, rowCount).Count(r => RowHasNull(data, r));

As you can see the variable `rowCount` doesn't exist. I guess you mean `oldRowCount`

Answer (score 3):

Well there is no LINQ `Where` for two dimensional arrays. If you can change your array definition to be an `object[][]` you can use a `foreach` to iterate through the "rows" and filter out rows that have all nulls.

```
public class RemoveNulls
{
    [Test]
    public void RemoveNullItems()
    {
        var items = new object[][] { new object[] { null, null }, new object[] { 1, 2 } };
        var cleanRows = new List<object[]>();
        foreach (object[] row in items)
        {
            var newRow = row.Where(item => item != null).ToArray();
            if (newRow.Any()) cleanRows.Add(newRow);
        }
        var result = cleanRows.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Did you already test your code ? I'm having an error at the line  :var newRow = row.Where(item => item != null).ToArray();

The exception is :

System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source'

Comment: This is normal, since the variable `row` is null at his first occurence.

Comment: `IList<object[]> cleanRows = Enumerable.Empty<object[]>().ToList();`? Is that just `var cleanRows = new List<object[]>();`?

Comment: @BoubacarTraoré Unfortunately I was thinking of an array of arrays rather than a two-d array. I'll delete for now until I can fix it.

Comment: @Ry- yes it is, nice catch

Comment: Thank you for your edit, but I prefer @dasblinkenlight solution since changing my array type to `object[][]` could affect my whole project. Thanks anyway !!

Comment: @BoubacarTraoré No worries, I'm sure that one will work with your 2d array better!